# Adding Flask server to create-react-app default app, 404 on /dist/bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, flask, webpack, http-status-code-404

I am trying to connect a flask server to a react app created with create-react-app, and using webpack to bundle it. I am largely following things I have learned working through [this](https://github.com/angineering/FullStackTemplate/tree/SIMPLE_WEBSITE) project and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKIHpoF8ZIk) accompanying video, except that I am using the default create-react-app as a starting point.

Here is my directory structure

```
-SimpleApp
--server
----server.py
----__init__.py
--static
----dist
------bundle.js
------styles.css
----node-modules
----src
----package.json
----package-lock.json
----webpack.config.js
----index.html
----__init__.py
--venv
```

basically my "static" folder is the default react-app, plus an index.html, a config file, and an empty **init**.py.

My server.py is simple, and in it I set my static_folder and template_folder

## server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='..static/dist', template_folder='../static')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

it calls my index.html which looks like

## index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles.css">
    <title>simple app</title>
   </head>
 <body>
    <div id="root" />
    <div>Hello</div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

my webpack.config.js is

## webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname + '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader',
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

and

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "simpleapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Fullstack Template",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev-build": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

I run npm run watch and python server.py and I get

```
"GET /dist/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /dist/bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

It seems like this traces back to index.html. I don't think my config or package files have anything to do with it, but I am new to writing these and don't want to misunderstand.

The not-found files are in my app's static_folder, why would it not be able to find them?

I may be missing some fundamental concepts. If so please point me in the right direction

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='..static/dist', template_folder='../static')
```

The above is probably confusing things, and `..static` is not the same as `../static`

**EDIT**: Just had a look at the tutorial you linked.  I'll leave the answer I wrote previousy below, but fixing the above typo to `static_folder='../static/dist`
may be a quicker fix for your issue.

---

Personally, I'd simplify this by doing the following:

- Note that your `server.py` sits in the `server` directory
- Create 2 subdirectories in this `server` directory: `templates` and `static`
- Move index.html to `server/templates`
- Move all the static files, including the `dist` subdirectory to `server/static`

Now the directory structure should look more like:

```
SimpleApp
└── server
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── server.py
    ├── static
    │   └── dist
    │       ├── bundle.js
    │       └── styles.css
    └── templates
        └── index.html
```

Then just initialize the app with:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

No need to define the static & template directories here, as you've laid it out in the default structure which Flask expects.

Try to hit: `http://localhost:5000/static/dist/bundle.js` in the browser and confirm this loads correctly.

Then update the template to load these files from the correct location, using `url_for` in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/styles.css') }}"
>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/bundle.js') }}"
>
```

If you regenerate `bundle.js` at a later point, you may need to also tweak the webpack config to place it in the new location.

Comment: Awesome thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I feel silly having had to ask a question about a simple typo, but I'm glad to have also gotten feedback on directory organization. It can be a surprisingly odd thing to figure out.

Comment: Yeah I found flask slightly tricky to get started with because there's so many different ways to arrange the code, and fundementals often get missed when following tutorials because everyone has a slightly different application layout.

Comment: I am going to jump back on this post because now I'm having an error with the same project. I did as you first suggested, changing static_folder="../static/dist", and it worked. I decided to rebuild the project formatted to your suggestion, when I ran "npm run watch" I get

Comment: npm ERR! simpleapp@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fullstack-template@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.```

Comment: Then I went back to run the original project, which I had previously gotten working, and it no longer worked and gave me the exact same error. I changed nothing about the project between when it worked and when it didn't. I apologize about not knowing how to format the code in the comments.

Comment: Never mind, I figured this one out. In my config file I need to change "path: path.join(__dirname + '/dist')," to just "path: __dirname + '/dist',". I don't know why the path.join function breaks one app but not the other, but at least it works.